# vegdist Error: input data must be numeric

Tags: r, vegan, vegdist

I tried to run dist.cor <- vegdist (data, method="bray") to calculate the dissimilarity index but I got an error:"Error in vegdist(data, method = "bray") : input data must be numeric.

It's my first time using the package "vegan", I have a table with indexes calculated for the presence of prey DNA in gut contents. The first four columns are the factors (location, species, sex and size) I want to test later on (using a PERMANOVA) and the rest are the index calculated per sample (gut) per prey item. I want to calculate the dissimilarity using bray-curtis but this error comes up: "Error in vegdist(data, method = "bray") : input data must be numeric.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or what I should change to be able to calculate the dissimilarity and then perform the PERMANOVA according to it.
[data in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOJW7.png)

Comment: So your dataset has got character type data in there - loc_cod, species, sex, size.
If you load the vegan example dataset (with `data(varespec)`) and then inspect the varespec dataset you'll see that each column has numeric data only. I suggest (if it makes sense) that you do `data %>% select(OTU1:OTU12) %>% vegdist(method = "bray")` to get rid of the character columns and run vegdist on just the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Could you seperate the dataframes to run the analysis on? Take only your columns containing the index data then run df <- as.numeric(df). Then you should be able to do the analysis.

Comment: hi mlp206, welcome to Stack Overflow! Is this an answer or a question, or a comment? seems unclear at the moment!